# how does cublas implement asynchronous scalar variable transmission

Tags: cuda, cublas

in many cublas or cusparse function calls, they use scalar variables which we can pass in either host pointer or device pointer, such as the alpha and beta variable here
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemm

How is this actually implemented? If the data is in host, I assume it would need to allocate memory on device and then call cudaMemcpyAsync to copy the data. However, doing cudaMalloc would make the function call synchronous. How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a host resident scalar it can be passed by value as a kernel parameter. If it's device resident then a pointer to it can be passed as a kernel parameter.

Comment: I see, do you mean if it is a host resident scalar then the value which the kernel will be using is taken at the time when the kernel is called? If this is the case, then I'm not allowed to do asynchronous memory copy from device to host then pass the target host address to those functions like cublas gemm?

Comment: A parameter passed to a function in C is expected to be valid when the function is called.  The same is true for a kernel.  If we were only talking about kernel calls, your asynchronous memcopy issued *in the same stream* would be OK, since (even aync) calls issued to the same stream are serialized.  Subsequent kernel calls in that stream will not begin until previously issued cudaMemcpyAsync operations are complete.  But calling a cublas function is not the same as a bare kernel call.  Treat it like a c function.  Anyway, this all seems besides the point of your original question.

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm, do you mean if I do `cudaMemcpyAsync(&h_alpha, &d_alpha, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);` follow by `cublasSgemm(..., &h_alpha, ...);`, it won't work because the value of `h_alpha` is taken by `cublasSgemm` immediately when it is called, which could happen before the memory copy?

Comment: `cudaMemcpyAsync` returns control to the calling thread immediately, without waiting for the memcpy operation to complete.  `cublasSgemm` is an ordinary C API function call. I can't tell you whether it would or would not work.  But I wouldn't do that.  I don't intend to continue responding to new questions posed in the comments.  I've attempted to answer your original question.  The transfer of data to a kernel need not require a `cudaMalloc`/`cudaMemcpy` operation, if the data is transmitted via kernel parameters.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just trying to make my library behaves exactly the same as the existing library. So far I'm still puzzled by the implementation of the scalar parameter.

Comment: I just tested it and it seems that it's not like what you said. I first do cudaMemcpyAsync for a 5GB of memory from device to host and then pass the last element in host memory as "alpha" to the cublassSgemm function. I then look at the result to see whether cublas used the value before or after copying. It turns out that cublas is using the value after copying.

Comment: You mean it's not like what I said when I said "I can't tell you whether it would work or not?" It's likely working because the `&h_alpha` pointer is valid at the C api function call, while under the hood cublas prepares a kernel to complete the gemm operation.  The kernel uses `h_alpha` as a parameter (the host pointer would serve no purpose) and the kernel waits until the preceding cuda operations in the same stream have completed.  Again, I'm just speculating.  If you want to depend on that behavior (seems undocumented to me) go ahead.  I don't see anywhere where I said it wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm referring to your answer, that "If its a host resident scalar it can be passed by value as a kernel parameter", this seems not true, otherwise I would see cublas calculate the matrix multiplication using the host memory value before copying has finished.

Comment: I think maybe your test is not valid.  Here is [my test](http://pastebin.com/bLZbb7fp).  The `cublasSgeam` operation is using the host result (`h_data[DSIZE-1]`) before the copying is complete.  If you un-comment the `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` line, the cublas result will change (to zero), meaning that the cublas operation then uses the value after copying is complete.

Comment: Thank you for the test. Yes you were right. I was using `malloc` instead of `cudaHostAlloc`, which make all memory copy synchronous. Thank you very much for helping me.